# Network error and Axios Error when running axios with graphQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, graphql, cors

I have a js file where I am running a simple `axios post` function with graphQL and am getting the following errors:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://test.com' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.


index.js:38 M {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
```

My code:

```
const headers = {
  "content-type": "application/json",
  Authorization: "myToken",
};


const query = `
query($id: ID!) {
  workspace(id: $id) {
    name
    company {
      name
    } 
  }
}`;
let vars = { id: "123456" };


  axios({
    url: "https://test.com/graphql",
    data: {
      query,
      vars,
      headers,
    },
  })
    .then((res) => console.log(res))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <title>My Class</title>
</head>
<body>
     <p class="myClass" id="myID">Click Here</p>

<script src="index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Server is a node-express server. I wanted to use axios using node but I need this data on the browser side on click so decided to use axios without node. Not sure why I am getting the error mentioned above.

Comment: add cors to your server that's running at test.com

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly, how do I do that?

Comment: read docs about adding cors to nodejs server